Animated, 90s?, man and talking dog, aired on Cartoon Network
I'm trying to recall a full-length animated movie I saw on Cartoon Network as part of an evening (?) movie block, mid- to late-90s. 
All I can remember is that it was about a man (tall, dressed in black?) and a talking dog (squat, brown?) in a city full of gears, clocks? Nothing about the actual plot, may have been about sticking it to the man... dystopia... something. The animation style was minimalistic, kind of Ronald Dahl-ish, kind of Jon Scieszka-ish. 
One other thing is that, during the credits, one of the main characters (maybe the dog) was credited "As Himself".

Any of these maybe? http://cartoonnetwork.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Dogs

Was it "Twice Upon a Time" (1983)?



Aired on Cartoon Network 1998 (1) and featured a talking dog (at one point: he is "Ralph the All-Purpose Animal"), whimsical hand-drawn (chaotic) Illustratisch art style and does have a man-in-black character.
The plot involves stopping the cosmic clock and saving people from nightmares.

Possibly it's Courage the Cowardly Dog. It's a sort of creepy/comedy cartoon series, but I think there was also a movie.
The picture on the IMDB page should ring a bell if this is what you're looking for.
